# Create android project via cmd

Tags: android, cmd, project

I cannot create a android project via cmd.

The following error is shown:

```
flag -- is not valid
```

I tried to execute the following code

According to android training [website](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)

```
android create project --target <target-id> --name MyFirstApp \ --path <path-to-workspace>/MyFirstApp --activity MainActivity \ --package com.example.myfirstapp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've added a space somewhere you shouldn't or had trouble substituting the stuff in <> with actual values, or maybe been confused by the newlines.

Here is a command with just one line that I just ran on OSX that successfully created a project in ~/MyFirstApp.

```
android create project --target "android-17" --name MyFirstApp --path ~/MyFirstApp --activity MainActivity --package com.example.myfirstapp
```

This should work for you, assuming you have the android-17 SDK installed. If you have another SDK installed, then you'll have to change the number to represent the SDK you have installed. (run `android list targets` to see which ones you have)